# STATA extraction of 1:1 neighbourghood matching doing a loop

Tags: loops, date, stata, nearest-neighbor

I am using data extracted from Morningstar. I would like to perform for each month (from 2018m6 to 2023m4) a 1:1 neighbourhood matching using

```
 teffects nnmatch
```

I think that the problem of my code comes from the date I am looping over, but I don't know how I could solve this problem (I am quite new to coding).

Below is the code I wrote, the output is "type mismatch" :

```
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
* NAME: 1:1 matching.do     
* CREATED:  19/06/2023                  
* CREATED BY: Marie 
* LAST MODIF:   19/06/2023
* MODIFIED BY: Marie
* Objective : 1:1 neighbourhood matching
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
clear all
set more off

* Enter your global pathway below *
cd "/Users/Documents/Data"
use "Merged_Morningstar.dta"
ssc install nnmatch

*  Define the time periods to loop over *
local start_year = 2018
local start_month = 6
local end_year = 2023
local end_month = 4

* Convert start and end dates to numeric format *
local start_date = ym(`start_year', `start_month')
local end_date = ym(`end_year', `end_month')

* Loop over the time periods *
local t = `start_date'
while `t' <= `end_date' {
    * Extract year and month from the current date *
    local year = year(`t')
    local month = month(`t')
    
    * Subset the data for the current time period *
    keep if year(_j) == `year' & month(_j) == `month'

    * Perform 1:1 neighborhood matching with one match per observation *
    gen rownum = _n
    teffects nnmatch (FlowM€ Age SizeM€ Return Tenure Fees_new) (country), gen(nnid)

    * Extracting the dataset for treated funds *
    save "Matched_Complete_`year'_`month'.dta", replace
    keep if country == 1 & !mi(nnid1)
    save "/Users/mariemesnard/Documents/ESSEC/Master Thesis/Data/Matched_Treated_`year'_`month'.dta", replace

    * Extracting the dataset for control funds *
    use "Matched_Complete_`year'_`month'.dta"
    keep if country == 0 & !mi(nnid1)
    save "/Users/mariemesnard/Documents/ESSEC/Master Thesis/Data/Matched_Control_`year'_`month'.dta", replace

    * Drop unnecessary variables and rename variables *
    drop nnid1
    rename rownum nnid1
    save "Matched_Control_`year'_`month'.dta", replace

    * Merge the matched datasets for treated and control funds *
    merge 1:m nnid1 using "Matched_Treated_`year'_`month'.dta", keepusing(nnid1)
    keep if _merge == 3
    save "Matched_Sample_`year'_`month'.dta", replace

    * Append the matched dataset for treated funds to the final dataset *
    append using "Matched_Treated_`year'_`month'.dta", force

   * Increase the date by one month *
    local next_year = `year'
    local next_month = `month' + 1
    if `next_month' > 12 {
        local next_year = `next_year' + 1
        local next_month = 1
    }
    local t = ym(`next_year', `next_month')
}

* Final data *
save "Matched_Final.dta", replace
```

And _j has the format 2018m6, 2O18m9... 2023m4

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This isn't a miinimal reproducible for the simple reason that we can't access your datasets. That doesn't itself make this an insoluble problem but it makes less likely that anyone wants to work line by line through your code and try to imagine what is happening. WHere in the code do you get the error message?